# How do i change the title of an existing UIAlertAction?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a like button in an action sheet:

```
likeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Like this post", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        println("like pressed")
})
```

Once pressed I'd like to update the title to "Unlike this post"

Title is readonly and there isn't a SetTitle() function on UIAlertActions.

Ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Set a bool variable to indicate whether the post is "liked" then set the alert title conditionally.

Comment: Right... I was thinking about this the wrong way. Thank you. It helped to ask the question. :-)

Answer (score 7):

This works for me.

```
self.alertAction.setValue("New Title", forKeyPath: "title")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

This was answered by Lyndsey Scott [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168077/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-an-existing-uialertaction/31168225#comment50344038_31168077) on the original post.

> Set a bool variable to indicate whether the post is "liked" then set the alert title conditionally.